# Chart in R not displaying data

Tags: r, charts

I have the following data frame:

```
        vector_builtin  vector_loop     vector_recursive
1            0.00        0.10             0.34
2            0.00        0.10             0.36
3            0.00        0.08             0.36
4            0.00        0.11             0.34
5            0.00        0.11             0.36
```

I want to display the three columns in a line chart.

I have imported ggplot2 into R and the chart is displaying without data or lines in it.

**Code:**

```
library(ggplot2)
indexes <- row.names(df.new)
ggplot(df.new, aes(x=vector_recursive, y=indexes))
```

**Chart output**
[image]

**Output I want**
A chart showing the three series in a line chart.

[image]

Comment: You have character strings in `aes` for `x` and `y`, these are not labels. You have not assigned your data correctly, please look at the many tutorials online.

Comment: I've watched tutorials and I clearly posted the question, because I need directions.

Comment: Which would be your "Time (s)" and "Values" variables? In your data frame there are three variables: vector_builtin; vector_loop; vector_recursive. No one looks a time variable...

Comment: @Codinghierarchy A very basic graph is added in answer for your reference. At least you will get idea about how to assign data for plot. Time variable has been considered as `row number` in my example.

Comment: The basic problem is that you have not specified a geom (such as `geom_line`). That's why you see only a grey panel with no data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A very basic example using `ggplot2` and df from OP can be:

```
df <- read.table(text = "time vector_builtin  vector_loop     vector_recursive
1            0.00        0.10             0.34
2            0.00        0.10             0.36
3            0.00        0.08             0.36
4            0.00        0.11             0.34
5            0.00        0.11             0.36", header = T, stringsAsFactors = F)

p <- ggplot() +
     geom_line(aes(time, vector_builtin, colour = "red"), data =  df) + 
     geom_line(aes(time, vector_loop, colour = "green"), data =  df) +
     geom_line(aes(time, vector_recursive, colour = "blue"), data =  df) +
     labs(x="Time(s)", y="Value") + # Labels for axis 
     scale_color_manual("Data Types", values=c(red="red",green="green",blue="blue"),
                 labels=c("vector_builtin", "vector_loop", "vector_recursive" ))

print(p)
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that you have your data in a format that `ggplot2` understands. In your code, `geom_line` is expecting you to provide which columns in your data should correspond to which question. Below I have recreated your data, in the future, consider using `dput` to provide the data to others, which will help troubleshoot your specific issue.

```
df=data.frame(vector_builtin=c(0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00),
           vector_loop=c(0.10,0.10,0.08,0.11,0.11),
           vector_recursive=c(0.34,0.36,0.36,0.34,0.36))
```

However, you don't specify what your x axis is, so we will create a new variable that holds that information, for example:

```
df$x=1:5
```

Now, I would recommend reshaping the data into long format, which is preferred by `ggplot2`. You could also use the other answer here and specify each without that problem, but `reshape2`'s `melt` function could be used.

```
library(reshape2)
df.m = melt(df, id.vars="x")
```

Now when you correctly identify the names of the columns to plot, `ggplot2` will plot the data correctly:

```
ggplot() + geom_line(aes(color=variable, x=x, y=value), data=df.m)
```