# How do I plot multiple columns of a dataframe in ggplot?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm trying to plot a data frame that has "Date" as the x-axis, and stock price as the y-axis, and I have four different stocks to be plotted. I'm very confused by the ggplot documentation, and haven't found an easy solution to this. Here is the data frame:

```
appleData <- read.csv("AAPL.csv", header = TRUE)
microsoftData <- read.csv("MSFT.csv", header = TRUE)
googleData <- read.csv("GOOG.csv", header = TRUE)
amazonData <- read.csv("AMZN.csv", header = TRUE)

names(appleData) <- c("Date", "AAPL")
names(microsoftData) <- c("Date", "MSFT")
names(googleData) <- c("Date", "GOOG")
names(amazonData) <- c("Date", "AMZN")

mergedData1 <- merge(appleData, microsoftData, by = "Date")
mergedData2 <- merge(googleData, amazonData, by = "Date")
totalData <- merge(mergedData1, mergedData2, by = "Date")
totalData
```

The dataframe is called "totalData", and when I use ggplot(totalData) I get a blank plot. What I need help with specifically is plotting all four stocks onto the same plot, and also rescaling the prices so that they all begin at $100 (so they are on the same scale).

Comment: I had added one example at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48491246/chart-in-r-not-displaying-data/48491513#48491513 . It may help you.

Comment: Please post data as plain text, not images, so others can copy/paste it.

Comment: I tried this following exactly as it said and the warning says "geom_path: Each group consists of only one observation" Help?

Answer (score 1):

One of the main things I did was I converted your data from an untidy "wide" dataframe to a "tidy" long dataframe using the `gather` function from `tidyr`. I highly recommend that you check out this excellent tutorial http://garrettgman.github.io/tidying/ that goes into the basics of tidying. Once your data is "tidy" you will find many tools will work much easier!

```r
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(ggplot2)

# create sample data frame with random numbers
set.seed(123)
total_data <- data.frame(date = seq.Date(from = as.Date("2018-01-01"), 
                                             to = as.Date("2018-01-31"), by = "day"),
                         AAPL = sample(100:1000, 31),
                         MSFT = sample(100:1000, 31),
                         GOOG = sample(100:1000, 31),
                         AMZN = sample(100:1000, 31))
head(total_data)
#>         date AAPL MSFT GOOG AMZN
#> 1 2018-01-01  359  912  445  691
#> 2 2018-01-02  809  721  346  388
#> 3 2018-01-03  467  815  832  268
#> 4 2018-01-04  892  122  502  802
#> 5 2018-01-05  943  528  826  183
#> 6 2018-01-06  140  779  827  518

# convert your wide data frame to a tidy long data frame
total_data <- gather(total_data, company, value, -date)

# plot using ggplot2
total_data %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = date, y = value, color = company)) +
  geom_line()
```

Comment: I still keep getting the "Each group consists of only one observation" error... I printed my data "totalData" and it looks exactly like yours in the example.

Comment: @user9170959 can you post the code you are using to create the ggplot?